# How to plot graph sine wave

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this signal :

```
from math import*
Fs=8000
f=500
sample=16
a=[0]*sample
for n in range(sample):
    a[n]=sin(2*pi*f*n/Fs)
```

How can I plot a graph (this sine wave)?

and create name of xlabel as 'voltage(V)' and ylabel as 'sample(n)'

What code to do this?

Answer (score 52):

- Setting the `x-axis` with `np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)` gives an array from 0 to 1 in 0.001 increments.

  - `x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)` returns an array of 1000 points from 0 to 1, and `y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)` you will get the sin wave from 0 to 1 sampled 1000 times

I hope this will help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


Fs = 8000
f = 5
sample = 8000
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('sample(n)')
plt.ylabel('voltage(V)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

P.S.: For comfortable work you can use [The Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/).

Answer (score 23):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For ploting
import numpy as np # to work with numerical data efficiently

fs = 100 # sample rate 
f = 2 # the frequency of the signal

x = np.arange(fs) # the points on the x axis for plotting
# compute the value (amplitude) of the sin wave at the for each sample
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f * (x/fs)) 

#this instruction can only be used with IPython Notbook. 
% matplotlib inline
# showing the exact location of the smaples
plt.stem(x,y, 'r', )
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: `% matplotlib inline` this instruction can only be used with IPython Notbook.

Comment: integer division only result in integer prior to python 3, so `i/fs` only results in float when run on python 3, for python 2, set `fs = 100.0` as workaround

Comment: `[ np.sin(2*np.pi*f * (i/fs)) for i in x]` can be simplified to `np.sin(2*np.pi*f *(x/fs))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

F = 5.e2          # No. of cycles per second, F = 500 Hz
T = 2.e-3         # Time period, T = 2 ms
Fs = 50.e3        # No. of samples per second, Fs = 50 kHz
Ts = 1./Fs        # Sampling interval, Ts = 20 us
N = int(T/Ts)     # No. of samples for 2 ms, N = 100

t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t)

plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import math
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()
ws.bgcolor("lightblue")
fred = turtle.Turtle()
for angle in range(360):
    y = math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    fred.goto(angle, y * 80)

ws.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 2):

The window of usefulness has likely come and gone, but I was working at a similar problem. Here is my attempt at plotting sine using the turtle module.

```
from turtle import *
from math import *

#init turtle
T=Turtle()

#sample size
T.screen.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,1,1) 

#speed up the turtle
T.speed(-1)

#range of hundredths from -1 to 1
xcoords=map(lambda x: x/100.0,xrange(-100,101))

#setup the origin
T.pu();T.goto(-1,0);T.pd()

#move turtle
for x in xcoords:
    T.goto(x,sin(xcoords.index(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to plot sine wave in python using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x=np.arange(0,3*np.pi,0.1)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("SINE WAVE")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline
x=list(range(10))
def fun(k):
     return np.sin(k)
y=list(map(fun,x))
plt.plot(x,y,'-.')
#print(x)
#print(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg') #use matplotlib backend TkAgg (optional)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_rate = 200 # sampling frequency in Hz (atleast 2 times f)
t = np.linspace(0,5,sample_rate)    #time axis
f = 100 #Signal frequency in Hz
sig = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*(t/sample_rate))
plt.plot(t,sig)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer will more helpful if you add explanation instead of only code.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to plot the sine wave.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg') #use matplotlib backend TKAgg (optional)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, 50000)       # time axis
sig = np.sin(t)
plt.plot(t,sig)
```

Comment: your answer will more helpful if you add explanation instead of only code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import *
Fs = 8000
f = 500
sample = 16
a = [0] * sample
for n in range(sample):
    a[n] = sin(2*pi*f*n/Fs)
```

> creating the x coordinates

```
Sample = [i for i in range(sample)]
```

> importing matplotlib for plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> adding labels and plotting

```
plt.xlabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Sample(n)')
plt.plot(Sample, a)
plt.show()
```