# How to plot a basic sine graph on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

HW problem: 
Use matplotlib to plot  ()  for x  ∈  [ 0 ,  /4 ,  /2 ,  3/4 ...  2 ]. Use both orange points and a green line.

notes in class don't talk about how to set axes or colours; I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to use Stack Overflow, please help!

Following code is what I have so far, but I want to add the orange points... If I need to totally change my code, I am okay with that.

```
x = [ (n*(pi/4)) for n in range(10) ]
a = [ sin(theta) for theta in x ]
plt.plot(x, a, 'g-', label='sine') 
plt.axis([0, (2*pi), -1, 1.0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot graph sine wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566692/how-to-plot-graph-sine-wave)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation for `plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). In particular, look at the "Other Parameters" section, and the list of keyword arguments. Every option you need is listed there.